# NSData: read contents of file

Tags: swift2, swift-playground

Here's the code:

```
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: "/Users/7stud/xcode_projects/iOS/my_json.json")
```

That code is in a playground, and I get nil for jsonData.  I didn't type the path: I dragged the file from Finder to a Terminal window, which enters the full path of the file at the point of the cursor.  Then I copied that absolute path and pasted it into my code--so no typo.

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:):

> **NSData**
>
> **+ dataWithContentsOfFile:**
>
> Creates and returns a data object by reading every byte from the file
>   specified by a given path.
>
> **Declaration**   OBJECTIVE-C
>   + (instancetype)dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
>
> **Parameters**
>   path | The absolute path of the file from which to read data.
>
> **Return Value**
>   A data object by reading every byte from the file specified by path. Returns nil if the data object could not be
>   created.

There's no Swift definition.

Comment: Are you using a playground? Or is this an OSX app? Swift playgrounds are sandboxed, they cannot simply access files outside of it.

Comment: Okay, !@#$!@#$.  It's a playground issue.  The code works fine in a project.

Comment: @luk2302, Yep.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and as a quick workaround I placed my file directly at the location returned by the NSFileManager and later accessed the file to read the contents.

Here is the snipped:

```
var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var path:String! = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first
var data = fileManager.contentsAtPath(path+"/a.txt")
try NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

I placed my file a.txt at the path returned by NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains method and was able to retrieve it in a string.